# How to avoid too many properties when binding Textbox details

Tags: mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a mvvm app with 22 textboxes.
In my "normal" wpf app I could make a list and then change settings to all the boxes likes this:

```
Brush MyBrush = Brushes.LightGray;
            foreach (var a in AllBoxes)
            {
                a.Background = MyBrush;
                a.IsReadOnly = true;
                a.IsTabStop = false;
            }
```

So in mvvm I need to make 3 bindings per textbox and create properties like:

```
private Brush _clr2;
        public Brush Clr2
        {
            get { return _clr2; }
            set
            {
                _clr2 = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Clr2);
            }
        }
```

Is there an easier way to do this and not make 66 properties?

Answer (score 1):

You create an UserControl for one TextBox with all bindings...with the ViewModel associated

```
<StackPanel>
   <TextBox .... /> 
</StackPanel>
```

Then you use ObservableCollection of your ViewModel and Create a ParentView with ItemControl:

`<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfTextBox}">`

And create an itemstemplate for the items in your ItemsControl

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>
```